# Completing UI Activity assignment

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a UI Lab for Android Programming that I'm trying to complete.  I think I'm close, yet so far away.  I have four activities that I'm working with but only three of them needed worked on.  Here is what I have.  I need help with what I'm missing.

Here's the first Activity which is **AddToDoActivity**

```
package course.labs.todomanager;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Priority;
import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Status;

public class AddToDoActivity extends Activity {

// 7 days in milliseconds - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
private static final int SEVEN_DAYS = 604800000;

private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

private static String timeString;
private static String dateString;
private static TextView dateView;
private static TextView timeView;


private Date mDate;
private RadioGroup mPriorityRadioGroup;
private RadioGroup mStatusRadioGroup;
private EditText mTitleText;
private RadioButton mDefaultStatusButton;
private RadioButton mDefaultPriorityButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_todo);

    mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    mDefaultStatusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.statusNotDone);
    mDefaultPriorityButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.medPriority);
    mPriorityRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.priorityGroup);
    mStatusRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.statusGroup);
    dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    timeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);

    // Set the default date and time

    setDefaultDateTime();

    // OnClickListener for the Date button, calls showDatePickerDialog() to show
    // the Date dialog

    final Button datePickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.date_picker_button);
    datePickerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDatePickerDialog();
        }
    });

    // OnClickListener for the Time button, calls showTimePickerDialog() to show
    // the Time Dialog

    final Button timePickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.time_picker_button);
    timePickerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showTimePickerDialog();
        }
    });

    // OnClickListener for the Cancel Button, 

    final Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            log("Entered cancelButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");

            //TODO - Implement onClick().  
            Intent intent = new Intent setResult;
            finish();
            
        }
    });

    //OnClickListener for the Reset Button

    final Button resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
    resetButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            log("Entered resetButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");

            //TODO - Reset data fields to default values
            setDefaultDateTime();
            mTitleText.setText("");
            mDefaultStatusButton.setChecked(true);
            mDefaultPriorityButton.setChecked(true);
            
        
        
        
        }
    });

    // OnClickListener for the Submit Button
    // Implement onClick().
    
    final Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            log("Entered submitButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");

            // Gather ToDoItem data  
            
            //TODO - Get Priority
            Priority priority = getPriority();

            //TODO -  Get Status
            Status status = getStatus();

            //TODO -  Title
            String titleString = mTitleText.getText().toString();

            // Date
            String fullDate = dateString + " " + timeString;

            // Package ToDoItem data into an Intent
            Intent data = new Intent();
            ToDoItem.packageIntent(data, titleString, priority, status, fullDate);

            //TODO - return data Intent and finish
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
            finish();
            
        }
    });
}

// Do not modify below here

// Use this method to set the default date and time

private void setDefaultDateTime() {

    // Default is current time + 7 days
    mDate = new Date();
    mDate = new Date(mDate.getTime() + SEVEN_DAYS);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(mDate);

    setDateString(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    dateView.setText(dateString);

    setTimeString(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

    timeView.setText(timeString);
}

private static void setDateString(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

    // Increment monthOfYear for Calendar/Date -> Time Format setting
    monthOfYear++;
    String mon = "" + monthOfYear;
    String day = "" + dayOfMonth;

    if (monthOfYear < 10)
        mon = "0" + monthOfYear;
    if (dayOfMonth < 10)
        day = "0" + dayOfMonth;

    dateString = year + "-" + mon + "-" + day;
}

private static void setTimeString(int hourOfDay, int minute, int mili) {
    String hour = "" + hourOfDay;
    String min = "" + minute;

    if (hourOfDay < 10)
        hour = "0" + hourOfDay;
    if (minute < 10)
        min = "0" + minute;

    timeString = hour + ":" + min + ":00";
}

private Priority getPriority() {

    switch (mPriorityRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
    case R.id.lowPriority: {
        return Priority.LOW;
    }
    case R.id.highPriority: {
        return Priority.HIGH;
    }
    default: {
        return Priority.MED;
    }
    }
}

private Status getStatus() {

    switch (mStatusRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
    case R.id.statusDone: {
        return Status.DONE;
    }
    default: {
        return Status.NOTDONE;
    }
    }
}

// DialogFragment used to pick a ToDoItem deadline date

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        setDateString(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

        dateView.setText(dateString);
    }

}

// DialogFragment used to pick a ToDoItem deadline time

public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                true);
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        setTimeString(hourOfDay, minute, 0);

        timeView.setText(timeString);
    }
}

private void showDatePickerDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

private void showTimePickerDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}

private void log(String msg) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i(TAG, msg);
}

}
```

Here's the second activity which is **ToDoItem**

```
package course.labs.todomanager;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.Intent;

// Do not modify 

public class ToDoItem {

public static final String ITEM_SEP = System.getProperty("line.separator");

public enum Priority {
    LOW, MED, HIGH
};

public enum Status {
    NOTDONE, DONE
};

public final static String TITLE = "title";
public final static String PRIORITY = "priority";
public final static String STATUS = "status";
public final static String DATE = "date";
public final static String FILENAME = "filename";

public final static SimpleDateFormat FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);

private String mTitle = new String();
private Priority mPriority = Priority.LOW;
private Status mStatus = Status.NOTDONE;
private Date mDate = new Date();

ToDoItem(String title, Priority priority, Status status, Date date) {
    this.mTitle = title;
    this.mPriority = priority;
    this.mStatus = status;
    this.mDate = date;
}

// Create a new ToDoItem from data packaged in an Intent

ToDoItem(Intent intent) {

    mTitle = intent.getStringExtra(ToDoItem.TITLE);
    mPriority = Priority.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra(ToDoItem.PRIORITY));
    mStatus = Status.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra(ToDoItem.STATUS));

    try {
        mDate = ToDoItem.FORMAT.parse(intent.getStringExtra(ToDoItem.DATE));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        mDate = new Date();
    }
}

public String getTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    mTitle = title;
}

public Priority getPriority() {
    return mPriority;
}

public void setPriority(Priority priority) {
    mPriority = priority;
}

public Status getStatus() {
    return mStatus;
}

public void setStatus(Status status) {
    mStatus = status;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return mDate;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    mDate = date;
}

// Take a set of String data values and 
// package them for transport in an Intent

public static void packageIntent(Intent intent, String title,
        Priority priority, Status status, String date) {

    intent.putExtra(ToDoItem.TITLE, title);
    intent.putExtra(ToDoItem.PRIORITY, priority.toString());
    intent.putExtra(ToDoItem.STATUS, status.toString());
    intent.putExtra(ToDoItem.DATE, date);

}

public String toString() {
    return mTitle + ITEM_SEP + mPriority + ITEM_SEP + mStatus + ITEM_SEP
            + FORMAT.format(mDate);
}

public String toLog() {
    return "Title:" + mTitle + ITEM_SEP + "Priority:" + mPriority
            + ITEM_SEP + "Status:" + mStatus + ITEM_SEP + "Date:"
            + FORMAT.format(mDate);
}

}
```

Here's the third activity which is **ToDoListAdapter**

```
package course.labs.todomanager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Status;

public class ToDoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// List of ToDoItems
private final List<ToDoItem> mItems = new ArrayList<ToDoItem>();

private final Context mContext;

private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

public ToDoListAdapter(Context context) {

    mContext = context;

}

// Add a ToDoItem to the adapter
// Notify observers that the data set has changed

public void add(ToDoItem item) {

    mItems.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

// Clears the list adapter of all items.

public void clear(){

    mItems.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

// Returns the number of ToDoItems

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return mItems.size();

}

// Retrieve the number of ToDoItems

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {

    return mItems.get(pos);

}

// Get the ID for the ToDoItem
// In this case it's just the position

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {

    return pos;

}

//Create a View to display the ToDoItem 
// at specified position in mItems

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    //TODO - Get the current ToDoItem
    final ToDoItem toDoItem = getItemPos();

    //TODO - Inflate the View for this ToDoItem
    // from todo_item.xml.
    LayoutInflater = itemLayout;
    RelativeLayout itemLayout = m.context.getSystemService(R.layout.todo_item);
    
    //TODO - Fill in specific ToDoItem data
    // Remember that the data that goes in this View
    // corresponds to the user interface elements defined 
    // in the layout file 

    //TODO - Display Title in TextView

    final TextView titleView = ItemLayout.findViewById;
    setTextView;

    //TODO - Set up Status CheckBox

    final CheckBox statusView = ItemLayout.findViewById(R.id.statusCheckBox);
    statusView.setChecked(checked) statusDone;
    
    statusView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            log("Entered onCheckedChanged()");
            
            //TODO - Set up and implement an OnCheckedChangeListener, which 
            // is called when the user toggles the status checkbox
            if isChecked ToDoItem.setStatus status.Done(true);
            else

        
        }
    });

    //TODO - Display Priority in a TextView

    final TextView priorityView = findViewByID(R.id.PriorityView);
    PriorityView.setToString();

    
    //TODO - Display Time and Date. 
    // Hint - use ToDoItem.FORMAT.format(toDoItem.getDate()) to get date and time String

    final TextView dateView = itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.dateView);
            dateView.setText(ToDoItem.FORMAT);

    // Return the View you just created
    return itemLayout;

}

private void log(String msg) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i(TAG, msg);
}

}
```

And here is the fourth activity which is **ToDoManagerActivity**

```
package course.labs.todomanager;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Priority;
import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Status;

public class ToDoManagerActivity extends ListActivity {

// Add a ToDoItem Request Code
private static final int ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST = 0;

private static final String FILE_NAME = "TodoManagerActivityData.txt";
private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

// IDs for menu items
private static final int MENU_DELETE = Menu.FIRST;
private static final int MENU_DUMP = Menu.FIRST + 1;

ToDoListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create a new TodoListAdapter for this ListActivity's ListView
    mAdapter = new ToDoListAdapter(getApplicationContext());

    // Put divider between ToDoItems and FooterView
    getListView().setFooterDividersEnabled(true);

    //TODO - Inflate footerView for footer_view.xml file

    TextView footerView = TextView().getLayoutInflater()
        .inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null);

    //TODO - Add footerView to ListView
    getListView fv = (ListView)findViewById(R.layout.footer_view);
    
    footerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            log("Entered footerView.OnClickListener.onClick()");

            //TODO - Attach Listener to FooterView. Implement onClick().
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AddToDoActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST);
        }
    });

    //TODO - Attach the adapter to this ListActivity's ListView
    getListView.footer_view.setAdapter(mAdapter, fv);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    log("Entered onActivityResult()");

    // TODO - Check result code and request code.
    // If user submitted a new ToDoItem
    // Create a new ToDoItem from the data Intent
    // and then add it to the adapter
    if requestCode == ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST {
        also if resultCode != RESULT_OK(true);
        new mAdapter++;
        
    }
}

// Do not modify below here

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Load saved ToDoItems, if necessary

    if (mAdapter.getCount() == 0)
        loadItems();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Save ToDoItems

    saveItems();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_DELETE, Menu.NONE, "Delete all");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_DUMP, Menu.NONE, "Dump to log");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_DELETE:
        mAdapter.clear();
        return true;
    case MENU_DUMP:
        dump();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void dump() {

    for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        String data = ((ToDoItem) mAdapter.getItem(i)).toLog();
        log("Item " + i + ": " + data.replace(ToDoItem.ITEM_SEP, ","));
    }

}

// Load stored ToDoItems
private void loadItems() {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        String title = null;
        String priority = null;
        String status = null;
        Date date = null;

        while (null != (title = reader.readLine())) {
            priority = reader.readLine();
            status = reader.readLine();
            date = ToDoItem.FORMAT.parse(reader.readLine());
            mAdapter.add(new ToDoItem(title, Priority.valueOf(priority),
                    Status.valueOf(status), date));
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != reader) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

// Save ToDoItems to file
private void saveItems() {
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                fos)));

        for (int idx = 0; idx < mAdapter.getCount(); idx++) {

            writer.println(mAdapter.getItem(idx));

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != writer) {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}

private void log(String msg) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i(TAG, msg);
}

}
```

Any thought on how to improve the cancelButton code in the AddToDoAcitivity?

```
final Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        log("Entered cancelButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");

        //TODO - Implement onClick().  
        Intent intent = new Intent setResult;
        finish();
        
    }
});
```

Comment: This question is very vague.  No one wants to do your homework, especially since you're presenting with a whole app worth of code.  On top of that, you don't even say what the problem is.  Next time tell us what the problem is, what you have already tried to do to fix the problem, and present the code where you think the problem is.

Comment: Sorry TylerAndFriends if you think I'm trying to get people to do my homework. I'm honestly trying to learn, you don't have to be an ass about it. I just want help in my  implementation. I don't know where my problems are. Just that I'm doing something wrong and don't know where to look, what better place than this, right. I guess not, since you have no intention of being helpful.

Comment: What is the problem ? What errors do you have ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

change your AddToDoActivity code like this

```
public class AddToDoActivity extends Activity {

// 7 days in milliseconds - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
private static final int SEVEN_DAYS = 604800000;

private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

private static String timeString;
private static String dateString;
private static TextView dateView;
private static TextView timeView;


private Date mDate;
private RadioGroup mPriorityRadioGroup;
private RadioGroup mStatusRadioGroup;
private EditText mTitleText;
private RadioButton mDefaultStatusButton;
private RadioButton mDefaultPriorityButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_todo);

    mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    mDefaultStatusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.statusNotDone);
    mDefaultPriorityButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.medPriority);
    mPriorityRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.priorityGroup);
    mStatusRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.statusGroup);
    dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    timeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);

    // Set the default date and time

    setDefaultDateTime();

    // OnClickListener for the Date button, calls showDatePickerDialog() to show
    // the Date dialog

    final Button datePickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.date_picker_button);
    datePickerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDatePickerDialog();
        }
    });

    // OnClickListener for the Time button, calls showTimePickerDialog() to show
    // the Time Dialog

    final Button timePickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.time_picker_button);
    timePickerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showTimePickerDialog();
        }
    });

    // OnClickListener for the Cancel Button, 

    final Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            log("Entered cancelButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");
            finish();
        }
    });

    //OnClickListener for the Reset Button

    final Button resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
    resetButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            log("Entered resetButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");
            setDefaultDateTime();
            mTitleText.setText("");
            mDefaultStatusButton.setChecked(true);
            mDefaultPriorityButton.setChecked(true);                        

        }
    });

    // OnClickListener for the Submit Button
    // Implement onClick().

    final Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            log("Entered submitButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");

            // Gather ToDoItem data  

            Priority priority = getPriority();

            Status status = getStatus();

            String titleString = mTitleText.getText().toString();

            // Date
            String fullDate = dateString + " " + timeString;

            // Package ToDoItem data into an Intent
            Intent data = new Intent();
            ToDoItem.packageIntent(data, titleString, priority, status, fullDate);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
            finish();

        }
    });
}

// Do not modify below here

    // Use this method to set the default date and time

    private void setDefaultDateTime() {

        // Default is current time + 7 days
        mDate = new Date();
        mDate = new Date(mDate.getTime() + SEVEN_DAYS);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(mDate);

        setDateString(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
                c.get(Calendar.YEAR));

        dateView.setText(dateString);

        setTimeString(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

        timeView.setText(timeString);
    }

    private static void setDateString(int dayOfMonth, int monthOfYear, int year) {

        // Increment monthOfYear for Calendar/Date -> Time Format setting
        monthOfYear++;
        String mon = "" + monthOfYear;
        String day = "" + dayOfMonth;

        if (monthOfYear < 10)
            mon = "0" + monthOfYear;
        if (dayOfMonth < 10)
            day = "0" + dayOfMonth;

        dateString = year + "-" + mon + "-" + day;
    }

    private static void setTimeString(int hourOfDay, int minute, int mili) {
        String hour = "" + hourOfDay;
        String min = "" + minute;

        if (hourOfDay < 10)
            hour = "0" + hourOfDay;
        if (minute < 10)
            min = "0" + minute;

        timeString = hour + ":" + min + ":00";
    }

    private Priority getPriority() {

        switch (mPriorityRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
        case R.id.lowPriority: {
            return Priority.LOW;
        }
        case R.id.highPriority: {
            return Priority.HIGH;
        }
        default: {
            return Priority.MED;
        }
        }
    }

    private Status getStatus() {

        switch (mStatusRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
        case R.id.statusDone: {
            return Status.DONE;
        }
        default: {
            return Status.NOTDONE;
        }
        }
    }

    // DialogFragment used to pick a ToDoItem deadline date

    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);


            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int dayOfMonth, int monthOfYear,
                int year) {
            setDateString(dayOfMonth, monthOfYear, year);

            dateView.setText(dateString);
        }

    }

    // DialogFragment used to pick a ToDoItem deadline time

    public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                    true);
        }

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            setTimeString(hourOfDay, minute, 0);

            timeView.setText(timeString);
        }
    }

    private void showDatePickerDialog() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

    private void showTimePickerDialog() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }

    private void log(String msg) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i(TAG, msg);
    }

}
```